# How to save a related entity using Entity Framework in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orm, entity-framework-4.1, entity-relationship

I am pretty new to Entity Framework. I am getting an error as

> An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an
>   object context

I think I am doing something wrong.

I have a `Customer` table and `Address` table where the `Address` table has customer's ID as foreign key.

I want to add a new address to the customer entity and keep in session and in next call I want to save it. this is only an example.

```
using (var db = new MyModel())
{
    Customer cust = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => C.ID == 1);
    Address addr = new Address();
    addr.Street = "123 super st";
    cust.Addresses.Add(addr);   
    Session["customer"] = cust;         
}   

Customer SessionCustomer = (Customer)Session["customer"];
Customer.Comments = "Added new address"; 

using (var db = new MyModel())
{
    db.Customers.Attach(SessionCustomer); //This throws exception: An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context
    db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(SessionCustomer, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
    db.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Any help is appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `db.Customers.AddObject()` for reattaching object to datacontext.

 Take also a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.addobject.aspx

Cheers

Comment: But, the customer object is not new. It is something that is already existing in database.. the new thing is the address and probably more related objects might be added while Customer object is in session. And finally have to save it.  thanks for the resposne.